# Backbone not communicating with rails controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working my way through a simple Backbone JS app using Rails 4.1, and am having some trouble getting my data from the controller to the Collection.

I have setup a Model, View, Collection, and Router for the app, but when the index view renders, I get nothing returned. When I try to hit the js app's initialize in the console, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined`

Which is referring to 'data', which is passed into the initialize function from the rails controller.

After some debugging, I'm seeing my controller is receiving the following error when trying to call `initialize` on the js app:

```
NoMethodError: private method `initialize' called for TodoList:Module
```

My setup is as follows:

Controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
    respond_with(@tasks)
  end
end
```

Backbone App:

```
var TodoList = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {}, 
  Routers: {},

  initialize: function(data) {
    this.tasks = new TodoList.Collections.Tasks(data.tasks);
    new TodoList.Routers.Tasks();
    Backbone.history.start();
  }
};
```

Backbone Router:

```
TodoList.Routers.Tasks = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'index'
  },

  index: function() {
    alert('I cannot get this text to render');
  }
});
```

Backbone Model:

```
var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Backbone Collection:

```
TodoList.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Task,
  url: '/tasks'
});
```

UPDATE

tasks/index.html/erb, where TodoList.initialize is called from:

```
<%= content_for :javascript do %>
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
        TodoList.initialize({ tasks: <%== @tasks.to_json %> });
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where do you call `TodoList.initialize` in your JavaScript? Something is very confused here. That `TypeError` is a JavaScript error but the `NoMethodError` is a Ruby error. You're trying to call `TodoList.initialize` in Ruby but you want to say `TodoList.initialize(some_javascript_data)` in JavaScript.

Comment: I call TodoList.initialize from my index.html.erb file... I'll attach in an update above.  And I imagine its a ruby error because im using pry to debug on the ruby side...maybe that's a red herring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I realized I was missing the following line from my `application.html.erb` layout file that referenced my javascript

`<%= yield :javascript %>`